# Sending a @RequestPart List<String> as Post Request Body gives Content-Type Error

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, arraylist, postman

I'm trying to develop a POST API request which accepts Request as Form Data where a key has list of string as value. 
When I send the Request via POSTMAN, it gives me error saying message": "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported",

I tried to test the API using CURL and it worked but when I pass it using Postman it gives the error.

My API Code:

```
    @PostMapping(value= "/column", produces = "application/json", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String searchEntIdColumn(
            @RequestPart(value = "ENT_ID") String entId,
            @ApiParam("Indices to Search; Search Default Indices or Specify a List ")
            @Nullable @RequestPart(value = "SearchIndices") List<String> searchIndices) {

        LOGGER.debug("SearchController: searchEntIdColumn() :: Search Term is : ENT_ID = {} "
                + "on searchIndices : {} ", entId, searchIndices);


        return responseBuilderService.searchColumn(searchIndices, entId);
    }
```

The Postman gives  following Error: 
[image]

```
 {
    "timestamp": "2019-08-29T16:49:33.469+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported",
    "path": "/search/column"
}
```

But When I pass the SearchIndices List as null/empty, It runs successfully , but when I pass a list/string, it fails
[image]

Comment: we use springboot 2.1.x and  @PostMapping(value = "/v1/rest", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) with @RequestBody PreviewV1 previewRequest and it seem to work without specifying consumes

Comment: @KalpeshSoni If I use RequestBody, how can I refer to the key value in the form request body? Can you show some sample code, I don't want to use a class for my request body

Comment: as far as I know @RequestPart is used to upload files, if you are posting a json, by nature it is an object in java, why dont you want a class?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni, Yeah you said is right, I changed it to Request Body instead of Request Part and got it done. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Content-Type header in the request to "multipart/form-data". As the error clearly says the Content type is different.

Comment: I tired giving and still its the same errror. 

When I pass a null List for the SearchIndices, it gives me data

Comment: Could you please post the image of headers tab also?